# aarch64 Linux Hard float or soft float

Tags: linux, arm

The linux system has arm64 having arm architecture armv8-a. How to know whether debian is running hard float or soft float?

Answer (score 6):

In compliance with AAPCS64, GNU GCC for armv8 **only provides the hard float aarch64 toolchain**. This is unlike GCC for armv7-a, which provides *arm-linux-gnueabi* soft float toolchain and *arm-linux-gnueabihf* hard float toolchain.

Comment: Thank you for answering yourself, because I've been trying to figure out this exact thing the past 15 minutes or so.  Most people just move on without answering!