# How do I prevent rustlib from referencing soft float functions on aarch64?

Tags: rust, cross-compiling

I'm cross-compiling a Rust program to armv8 / aarch64 with the `aarch64-unknown-linux-musl` target. Building fails during linking due to a number of missing symbols all related to soft floats (`addtf3`, `multf3`, `subtf3` and more). These are referenced by `vfprintf` in `~/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/liblibc-f904a5ce7e6fe846.rlib`.

Is this a bug in the `aarch64-unknown-linux-musl` target? As I understand from [aarch64 Linux Hard float or soft float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61114429/aarch64-linux-hard-float-or-soft-float) soft floats are not supported by GCC on aarch64. Does that extend to Rust?

Or is there some other way to configure Rust not to include references to soft float functions?

Comment: Seems like [you're not the first with this problem](https://github.com/rust-lang/compiler-builtins/issues/201). That thread points to [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/46651) comment saying that compiling with the `--link-arg=-lgcc` should work. And you should be able to put it in `./.cargo/config.toml` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50646443/9363973)

Answer (score 1):

Based on MindSwipe's comment, soft-floats are provided by libgcc. I added this to my config.toml:

```
[target.aarch64-unknown-linux-musl]
linker = "aarch64-linux-musleabi-gcc"
rustflags = [ "-C", "target-feature=+crt-static", "-C", "link-arg=-lgcc" ]
```